# Is it possible to map one “entertaining” puzzle to a graph to consider a solution existence problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, puzzle

There is a puzzle which presents a field with $n$ by $m$ cells. The cells are the parts of the field, and in general, depending on a task, the cells can be united in a square or rectangle or in another geometric figure, for example, in a sequence of rectangles connected by their edges. For simplicity let us consider squired fields with dimension $n$ by $n$. The cells of the fields in this puzzle are of two types: empty and filled. The empty ones are marked as white, the filled ones – as blue. The empty ones allow walking through themselves, and the filled ones doesn’t allow it, they are like a wall. The goal is to draw a chain of lines following one after another without lifting a pencil. The lines can only be drawn vertically and horizontally until an obstacle meeting. The obstacle will be a filled cell, or an edge of field, or a cell with already drawn a part of the line or lines. **It needs to keep going straight until it has met an obstacle. At meeting an obstacle it needs to turn left or right.** To start drawing is allowed from any empty cell to any of four directions (up, down, left or right).

Let us take a look at the first example:

[image]

The task is to find a route satisfying the above requirements. Looking over several variants, it can be found the following solution:

[image]

It can be intuitively supposed that the solution is unique. On starting from another cell to draw a line without lifting a pencil, cells with gaps appear, for instance:

[image]

Two cells have got empty – without lines. It does not satisfy the conditions above and therefore it cannot be accepted as a solution.

Let’s take a look at the second example:

[image]

This combination of empty and filled cells gives several solutions. Moreover they are presented in pairs:

[image]

[image]

These variants are solutions even at placing the start instead of the finish and vice versa. It is a kind of a “commutativity” between a start and finish. The next ones are symmetric relative to 180 degree rotation.

[image]

If you, reader, have been interested and attracted by this puzzle and have a wish to try to solve something of that on your own, then the following examples for this purpose:

[image]

Enumerating intuitively variants at small sizes of fields (5-to-5 for instance), to find solution is not so hard. It is much harder if a size of field presents two, three, four (etc.) digit numbers. At a big size of field, it would effectively be to use an algorithm implemented in a computer program. An algorithm for enumerating variants can be organized in different ways. Hypothetically there can exist such a way that the algorithm organized on it would work more effectively (would be optimized in computational complexity). But it’s another question. I guess it’s much more interested among the community of mathematicians to look at this problem analytically and to try to understand at which conditions of combining empty and filled cells a solution exists. A lot of questions appear afterwards – uniqueness of the solution as well, and others – e.g.: symmetry, rotation. But I suppose that the question about the existence of a solution would be basic. For instance, the following combinations don’t have any solutions (and it is once again the intuitive suggestion):

[image]

If it could be possible to map such a field into a graph then the graph theory could be applied to this problem and then I guess that the solution existence problem finding could be quite similar to the problem about “Seven Bridges of Königsberg”.

**Question**

How do you suppose this problem is solvable in the graph theory?

Comment: I don't understand why you say that the last two examples have no solutions. I can find a path in both e.g. just going row by row in the example on the right.

Comment: The immediate way I see to model this as a graph theory problem is as follows: For every white cell add a vertex. Connect vertices of neighboring cells with an edge. Now you are looking for a Hamiltonian path in the obtained graph.

Comment: @sebastian Thanks! For the last two, it's propably unlucky examples. Could you prompt from which cell you started to draw a line?

Comment: Just zigzag from left to right for the second one. For the first one zigzag until the third column, then zigzag horizontally.

Comment: @sebastian The problem - and the reason this is not just a Hamiltonian path problem - is that the path is required to keep going straight until it hits an obstacle.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks to the notice about keeping going straight. Let me clarify this condition in the formulation of the problem to be clearer.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Oh I missed this, thanks for the clarification. This also explains the confusion about the last two examples.